# How to show loading icon when queries are executed in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX request which runs when user click the button. I want to show loading icon during the execution of AJAX request. I used next code but it works not as I expected.

Let me try to explain the situation. When user click the button, in terminal I notice requests in the same time user don't see loading icon. When all requests are completed in terminal I see `200 OK` status. Only after that I see icon but for shot time. So my question is how to show icon when queries are executed in background?

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "some url adress",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset= utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
    })
    .always(function (dataOrjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHRorErrorThrown){
        $('#loading-icon').fadeIn();
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#loading-icon').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the `always()` handler will be executed once the request completes.

Start showing the loading icon before sending the request:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('#loading-icon').fadeIn();

    $.ajax({
        url: "some url adress",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset= utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#loading-icon').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It seems nice but why I have feel like we cheat little bit :D

Answer (score 1):

You create Simple funcetion like:

```
function loader() {
    if ($('#dv_Loading').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#dv_Loading').fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else {
        $('#dv_Loading').fadeOut('slow');

    }
}
```

Use This funcation like:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
loader();

    $.ajax({
        url: "some url adress",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset= utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
success: function (data) {

                        loader();
                    }
    });

});
```

Comment: how about using [`$('#dv_Loading').fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) instead

Comment: Replace my $('#dv_loading') to your $('#loading-icon') then use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611821/how-to-show-a-hidden-element-with-jquery/48611918#48611918
```

I hope works fine atleast for me

Similary in your case,

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
 url : "URL",
 data: { data },
 beforeSend: function(){
 $("#loading-icon").show();
 },
 complete: function(){
 $("#loading-icon").hide();
 },
  success:  function (response) {
 });
 });
  });
```